# Conflicting solc versions on Truffle-test

Tags: solc, truffle-test

I'm developing some smart contracts sing solc 0.7.0. I'm able to successfully compile and deploy the contracts, but when I try to run $truffle test I get the following error:

```
Using network 'development'.

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./test/TestSupperApp.sol

truffle/Assert.sol:5:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.7.0+commit.9e61f92b.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity >= 0.4.15 < 0.7.0;
^--------------------------------^
,truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol:2:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.7.0+commit.9e61f92b.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity >= 0.7.0 < 0.7.0; 
^-------------------------------^

Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.7.0, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity >= 0.4.15 < 0.7.0".
Please update your truffle config or pragma statement(s).
(See https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#compiler-configuration for information on
configuring Truffle to use a specific solc compiler version.)

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.1.41 (core: 5.1.41)
Node v11.14.0
```

That's the beginning of the testing code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.8.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/SuperApp.sol";

contract TestSuperApp
{
```

And the compiler configuration of my truffle-config looks like this:

```
  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.7.0",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: false,
      //    runs: 200
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    },
  },
```

How is it that DeployedAddresses.sol requires the compiler to use >=0.7.0 AND <0.7.0? And how can I fix it?

(OBS.: Obviously I should change the pragma statement, but since DeployedAddresses.sol is dynamically created at test time, it does not seems possible to directly change it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be referencing what version of solidity compiler you should be using for truffle. This can be updated within the truffle-config.js.

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.7.0"
    }
 }
```

(See https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#compiler-configuration for information on
configuring Truffle to use a specific solc compiler version.)

You should then ensure that all smart contracts and smart contract tests are using this compiler function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;
```

If you refer again to the error, it states the contracts do not match the solidity compiler version. (Assert.sol / DeployedAddresses.sol) - Just update the pragma statement to reference the version as above and to match what is set from your truffle-config.js and you should be good.